# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cv_bridge"

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created my `catkin` package like so:

```
 catkin_create_pkg dcp_processing sensor_msgs cv_bridge roscpp std_msgs image_transport
```

I don't edit anything, then I compile the package:

```
catkin_make
```

I get that error the `cv_bridge` is missing. I didn't add or edit anything in the package so everything is by default as it is created with `catkin_create_pkg`.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Kinetic ROS Distribution.

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cv_bridge" with   any of the following names:

    cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
    cv_bridge-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cv_bridge" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set   "cv_bridge_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cv_bridge" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has   been installed. Call Stack (most recent call first):   dcp_processing/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'cv_bridge'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found. CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cv_bridge" with   any of the following names:

    cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
    cv_bridge-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cv_bridge" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set   "cv_bridge_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cv_bridge" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has   been installed. Call Stack (most recent call first):   dcp_processing/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/jaouadros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/jaouadros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Makefile:640: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272151/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22cv_bridge%22/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:\

> I get that error the `cv_bridge` is missing.

well, is it? Do you have `ros-kinetic-cv-bridge` installed? What is the output of `rospack find cv_bridge`?

Adding it to your package as a dependency does not automatigically make it available.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-03**:
Yes I know but I did install ros full version so as I don't miss any package.
I get [rospack] Error: package 'cv_bridge' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Yes I know but I did install ros full version so as I don't miss any package.

Installing `ros-$distro-desktop-full` does not result in *all packages* getting installed. The various metapackages provide you with a convenient way to install a select set of them, but definitely not all. See [REP-142: ROS Indigo and Newer Metapackages - Desktop variants](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html#desktop-variants).

> I get
>
> ```
> [rospack] Error: package 'cv_bridge' not found
> ```

That would seem to indicate that `cv_bridge` is not installed on your machine. Check with `dpkg -l | grep cv-bridge`. If that also doesn't result in `cv_bridge` being found, then install it with (on Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-cv-bridge
```

and try again.

---

Edit: `cv_bridge` should be installed as part of [vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) which is (through `perception`) part of `desktop_full`, so not having `cv_bridge` would be strange if you did in fact install `desktop_full`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-03**:
`dpkg -l | grep cv-bridge` doesn't result anything so it is not installed. I just installed it and it works. Thanks! I want to know why it didn't get installed the first time when I installed ROS? usually I don't need to installed `cv_bridge` separately.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
I don't know why it didn't get installed. What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep desktop-full`?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-03**:
It doesn't show anything just like with `dpkg -l | grep cv-bridge`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
Then I guess you didn't "install ros full version" as you claimed earlier. Only `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` would install `cv_bridge` automatically.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-03**:
I just checked with this: `grep ros-kinetic ~/.bash_history` I found that I launched `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
According to everything I can find and verify `desktop_full` should install `cv_bridge`, so I'm not sure what happened.

You could see whether `/var/log/apt/history.log` or `/var/log/apt/term.log` contains anything that can shed some light.

**Comment by [Sam123](https://answers.ros.org/users/96030/sam123/) on 2022-03-10**:
hi @gvdhoorn

I'm getting same error Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cv_bridge" with   any of the following names
cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
cv_bridge-config.cmake

i am working with ROS2 foxy ,18.04.1-Ubuntu on AWS ec2 server.
after using this command $ dpkg -l | grep cv-bridge
output shows:ii  libcv-bridge1d:amd64                       1.12.3+ds-2       amd64        cv_bridge Robot OS package
ii  python-cv-bridge     1.12.3+ds-2              amd64        cv_bridge ROS package - Python bindings

when i use this command $ dpkg -l | grep desktop-full
it shows nothing.